# Limit number of concurrent threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running multiple threads based on the user input dates.
If user input 15 dates it runs 15 threads parallel and for 10 dates it's running 10 threads in parallel

I need to have a cap limit regardless of user input ,for example it should always runs 5 threads . I see  ExecutorService can do that but not sure how to implement the same

Below is my sample code and require how to implement ExecutorService on this -

```
   List<FactorialThread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

         int position = 0;
           for (String query:QueryList)

           {
                position++;
                Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread - "+ position);   
             System.out.println(" Inside run thread method executing the query for ..."+query + "for index " + position  );
             threads.add(new FactorialThread(FileName,query,Thread.currentThread().getName()));


           }




            for (Thread thread : threads) {
              //  thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.setName("Thread"+thread);
                thread.start();
            }
```

Comment: `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`

Answer (score 2):

It is relatively straight forward: you can create an ExecutorService that is based on a thread pool. Then the tasks that you submit to that service will be processed by the threads of the underlying pool.

See [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1069/threadpoolexecutor-java-thread-pool-example-executorservice) for a simple example. Or the "official" [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) from oracle on the subtle differences how to configure such thread pools.